# Align text next to an image with a fixed position and undetermined size?

Tags: html, css

So I'd like to align a couple of spans with text next to an image, which has a fixed position in the top left corner, however, I did some research and decided to try `max-height:5%;width:auto;height:auto;` in order to keep the size of the image relative to the navigation bar and your screen resolution. I want to accomplish something similar to the navigation bar on http://www.csgoswag.com, but I can't get the text to align properly. Also, I don't believe I'm using a good method to keep the size of the navigation bar and logo at a good size so it's not taking up too much of the page no matter your resolution. Any help fixing this issue would be appreciated, thank you.

here is a jsfiddle of my current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/bfqumkq7/

Edit: I also realize I would have to keep the size of the text the same as the navbar, how would I do that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `#nav` is `position:fixed` there is no need to use positioning of any elements in the div.

We'll use `display:inline-block` to align the elements horizontally.

The `#nav` is set to a `max-height:5%` so the logo can be `max-height:100%`.

As for the menu text the OP wanted this the same size as the `#nav` so I've set this to `5vh` (vertical height units).

I wouldn't recommend this last technique however..I'd use `em` or `px` instead and adjust as required.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bfqumkq7/1/)

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #0097FE;
}
#nav {
  background-color: #262626;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
}
#nav_container_full {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  ;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lqApacL.png" class='logo'>
    <div id='nav_container_full'>
      <span class="nav" href="index.html">Home</span>
      <span class="nav" href="index.html">Tokens</span>
      <span class="nav" href="index.html">Store</span>
      <span class="nav" href="index.html">Logout</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The logo still goes over the text though? But thanks for the rest